# Missing mathematical step in convolution sum

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory, convolution

I am looking at an example on convolution sums. In the example it states the following:

$$ \sum_{k=-\infty }^{n }2^{k} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n} $$

I feel I am missing some mathematical steps in between and have not been able to understand how it leads to \$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m-n}\$. Any clarification on how to get between these two steps is appreciated.

Comment: Belongs to Math Stack Exchange because it's a pure math related question.

Comment: @Carl Sure, I will ask it there. It's an example from signals and systems which is why I asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

The lhs of the equation, the \$k<0\$. So it is equivalent to saying \$(\frac{1}{2})^m\$ with \$m\$ now being positive. And as the lhs runs only up to \$n\$ and not up to 0, you get the additional \$-n\$ on the right hand side.